# UpdatePanel and ListView control do not show data from BLOB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-storage

I am trying to populate data (file names with hyperlink) from Azure Blob.

Here is my code:

**UpdatePanel:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="refreshButton" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="refreshButton_Click" />
        <asp:ListView ID="fileDisplayControl" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <asp:Hyperlink ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Hyperlink ID="filehyperlink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' /> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Inside Listview, I placed HYperlink control, where data is populated with hyperlink.

**Code to supply datasource to Listview control:**

```
private CloudBlobContainer getfileGalleryContainer()
{
    return _blobStorageService.getCloudBlobContainer();
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Blob container that contains the ppp
        // Perform a query of the its contents and return the list of all of the blobs whose name begins with the string "ppp". 
        // It returns an enumerator of their URLs and place that enumerator into list view as its data source. 

        fileDisplayControl.DataSource = 
            from o in getfileGalleryContainer().GetDirectoryReference("ppp").ListBlobs()
            select new { Url = o.Uri };

        // List view to bind to its data source
        fileDisplayControl.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately nothing is populated even though files are stored in ppp blob.

Does anyone please tells me whats the wrong in this process?

Comment: Did you check if there are `exceptions`?

Comment: Do not get any exception. Web-job is running and it produces the files but nothing come up

Comment: If this is real code, you will not see the exception because of `catch(Exception) { }` Remove the try/catch and try again.

Comment: It cannot create anything in the local Blob, probably that can be a reason. Even though when it is published in Azure and run, it creates files in Azure storage blob, but does not return anything in the LIstview. It does not show any error surprisingly

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. You have to check step by step what your problem is:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkMe1 = _blobStorageService.getCloudBlobContainer();
    var checkMe2 = checkMe1.GetDirectoryReference("ppp");
    var cehckMe3 = checkMe2.ListBlobs();
    var checkMe4 = from o in cehckMe3
                    select new { Url = o.Uri }.ToList();

    fileDisplayControl.DataSource = checkMe4;

    // List view to bind to its data source
    fileDisplayControl.DataBind();
}
```